# Can or Could - which one is correct to usein question

Tags: word-choice

Can you please shift a little? or Could you please shift a little?

which one of the two is correct?

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, many times before. Please [search the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=can+could) before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can is asking the question are you capable of it. Could is asking the question would you mind doing it. Both are grammatically correct. It's a matter of what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but the second is a little more polite. In practice, a native speaker would be more likely to say something like ‘Would you mind moving over a bit?’

Comment: thanks Barrie for the reply, can you please also explain what difference will it make to use would over could?

Comment: _Would you mind_ is more polite than either _could you_ or _can you_.